# Any examples on using complex key (array) and how to query with group_level parameter in Cloudant or CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

Would like to use a secondary index with MapReduce in Cloudant using a complex key (array) so I can aggregate a different levels like [YEAR, MONTH, DAY].   Can anyone share any examples?  Are there any limits to the number of elements in the array used for the key?

Answer (score 2):

Example of using group_level for dates: http://blog.wakatta.jp/blog/2012/01/30/seven-databases-in-seven-weeks-couchdb-day-2/

Example of using complex keys to aggregate geo data: http://examples.cloudant.com/simplegeo_places/_design/geo/index.html